# How to use friendly caller id name for CSID on Twilio fax

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When sending a fax using a Verified Caller ID I would like the CSID value being sent with the fax to be the friendly name of the verified caller id.  Currently it displays the phone number itself.  For example, in Twilio I have a verified caller id with the following values:

- Number: +1 234-567-8900
- Friendly Name: My Business

In this example the phone number is that of a real phone I have.  If I were to call from that real phone, the person who receives the call would see the text "ABC Business" on their caller ID.

However, whenever I send the "Remote CSID" shows up as the verified phone number itself - +12345678900 - rather than either the friendly name set up in Twilio - "My Business" - or the friendly text - "ABC Business" - that is registered to that phone number in whatever database houses real caller ids.

Is there a way to make the CSID be more friendly?

Here's my code (C#):

```
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var fax = FaxResource.Create(
            from: "+12345678900",
            to: "+19999999999",
            statusCallback: new Uri("http://fax.someaddress.com/fax/status"), 
            mediaUrl: new Uri("http://fax.someaddress.com/content/testdocs/document7.pdf")
        );
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Fax doesn't currently support setting the CSID to anything other than the `From` number you use to send the fax. This is on the roadmap, though I can't specify when it might become available.

I've registered your interest in being able to use this feature and will keep this answer up to date with progress. If you want a more direct contact about this, I recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: Thank you very much.  It's definitely something that would be helpful.  My client wants to make this as user friendly for their customers as possible, so modifying the CSID would be a nice enhancement.